# 404 Error for Java Server (Tomcat 7)

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

```
    HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)
```

I tried manually starting the server using

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

and i get this

```
Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status tomcat7.service
tried `systemctl status tomcat7.service`

```
  ● 
    tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
           Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
           Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-08 03:02:07 MST; 1min 50
             Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
          Process: 15031 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=1/FAIL

 Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomca
tomcat7[15031]:    ...fail!
 tomcat7.service: Control process exited, co
 Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
 tomcat7.service: Unit entered failed state.
tomcat7.service: Failed with result 'exit-c
```

I am trying to create a simple java servlet.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CloudComputing</display-name>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ReqResp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>cc.Cloudpi</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>ReqResp</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Cloudpi</url-pattern>

 </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Kindly help (Newbie Alert !)

Comment: Did you set it up correctly ?

Comment: yes it seems I have 2 tomcat7 installations and I am unable to find the location of the other tomcat server

As a work around I installed tomcat 8.5 and it works now.

Comment: Also the web.xml project name was incorrect that I changed later. (Still didnt work though)

Comment: try using `sudo dpkg -L tomcat` to find its location

Comment: Tried it and it seems like 1 installation  as it has no duplicates . This is strange !